# Firebase allow write without deletion at parent and child nodes

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I've been wrestling with Firebase security for a little while now and am not having much luck with a scenario that I don't think is very unique (but it is also not covered in the documentation).

Imagine I have a tree, `test_tree`, which is at the root of my Firebase database. From there, I have three children under `test_tree` named `requiredString1`, `requiredString2`, and `optionalString1`.

I would like for an authenticated user of the Firebase to be able to write to `test_tree`, and require that both of the `requiredString` children are included, while allowing `optionalString1` to be optional. There is one additional caveat which is throwing me for a loop -- **although `optionalString1` is optional, it should not be allowed to be deleted.**

So, with those requirements in mind, I've come up with the following security rules:

```
"rules" {

  "test_tree": {

    //Define overall write rules
    ".write": "
      auth !== null &&
      newData.exists() //this is done to ensure that a deletion of this tree cannot occur
    ",
    ".validate": "
      newData.hasChildren(['requiredString1', 'requiredString2'])
    ",

    //Define rules for each child
    "requiredString1":{
      ".validate": "
        newData.isString()
      "
    },

    "requiredString2":{
      ".validate": "
        newData.isString()
      "
    },

    "optionalString1":{
      ".validate": "
        newData.isString()
      "
    },

    //And finally, ensure no other miscellaneous children can be written
    "$other": {
      ".validate": false
    }
  },

  //Also, ensure lockdown on all other root trees
  "$other": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false,
    ".validate": false
  }
}
```

I've started to put together a test suite to test my rules as I go along, but the *optional-yet-not-delete* rule is causing problems.

With the above rules, I fail on two tests:

1. A write to `test_tree` with following payload is allowed (this needs to fail).

   ```
   {
     requiredString1: "string1",
     requiredString2: "string2",
     optionalString1: null
   }
   ```
2. A write to `test_tree/optionalString1` with payload of `null` is allowed (this needs to fail).

I've tried to get tricky with my validation rules, such as:

```
"rules": {
  ...
  ".validate": "
    //Ensure that required values are present
    newData.hasChildren(['requiredString1', 'requiredString2']) &&


    (
      //IF optionalString is included, ensure that it's not null
      (
        newData.hasChild('optionalString1') &&
        newData.hasChild('optionalString1').val() !== null
      )

      ||

      //But also allow it to be non-present
      !newData.hasChild('optionalString1')
    )
  "
  ...
}
```

But, unfortunately, this results in the same errors as before.

I've tried some other rule structures as well including actually moving the entire rule set into each child location (and removing the `.write` and `.validate` rules at the parent `test_tree` location), but then writes to the parent location (that previously worked) would then fail.

Some help here? Again, I would think that allowing data to be optional, yet still prevent deletion, would be a common need.

**EDIT 1:**

I've spent some time thinking about my question, and I think the requirement is a little bit of a misnomer. Basically, what I was asking for was that the data be optional *if and only if* it's not present in the Firebase database. If it *is present* in the Firebase, it essentially becomes required.

However, once I realized that was the true requirement, it made describing the use case easier. Hopefully, it'll be clear in a moment, but basically **the use case is protecting the developer that is interfacing with Firebase from themselves.**

Imagine there is a tree of several descriptors for an item, and the tree looks like the following:

```
items: {
  item_ID1: {
    name: "Item Name",
    descriptorA: "A descriptor",
    descriptorB: "Another descriptor"
  }
}
```

Basically, I was thinking that `descriptorA` and `descriptorB` would be optional, and the `name` would be required. In the event that `name` needed to be changed whereas `descriptorA` and `descriptorB` would remain the same, I wanted to protect the developer that is writing the interface to this data from being able to accidentally blast `descriptorA` and `descriptorB` by using a `.set({item_ID1: {name: "New Name"}})`.

I think this actually can be accomplished with the following rules:

```
"rules": {
  "items": {
    ".write": "
      auth !== null &&
      newData.exists()
    ",
    ".validate": "
      newData.hasChild('name') &&
      (
        !data.hasChild('descriptorA') || 
        (data.hasChild('descriptorA') && newData.hasChild('descriptorA'))
      ) &&
      (
        !data.hasChild('descriptorB') || 
        (data.hasChild('descriptorB') && newData.hasChild('descriptorB'))
      )
    ",
    "name": {
      ".validate": "newData.isString()"
    ",
    "descriptorA": {
      ".validate": "newData.isString()"
    ",
    "descriptorB": {
      ".validate": "newData.isString()"
    ",
    "$others": {
      ".validate": false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `"optionalString1":{ ".validate": "newData.isString() || !data.exists()" },`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I'm not sure how that would work, considering how the [Validating Data Guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-validate) is written. To quote, "The .validate rules are the only type of security rule which does not cascade. If any validation rule fails on any child record, the entire write operation will be rejected. **Additionally, the validate definitions are ignored when data is deleted (that is, when the value is null).**" The bolded sentence is the crux of my problem, I believe.

Comment: Check line 34 of the last example on that page. Or better yet, give my snippet a spin.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I gave the snippet a spin with no success. Actually, it resulted in an additional test failure -- with no data at that location, it allows a non-string value to be written.

Comment: Checking now. There's a weird combination indeed. This might require validating at a higher level, which we usually don't do. Check that line 34 again. It's a `.write` rule, not a `.validate` rule. I'll write up an answer.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I noticed that it was a `.write` rule that you had referred to, the issue with that is that `.write` rules cascade to children. So, if the parent `.write` rule succeeds, then aren't the children `.write` rules ignored?

Comment: From what I can tell, there's not a great way to distinguish between something being deleted versus something simply not being included. Without a null check, i.e. something like `isNull()`, Firebase rules are seemingly limited in what they can accomplish which is a big downer (I hope I'm wrong).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91522/discussion-between-frank-van-puffelen-and-mandm).

Answer (score 3):

The first problem is (as you said) that `.validate` rules are not executed if there is no new data. So you'll need to detect the condition in a `.write` rule.

The second problem (as you also said) is that "rules cascade", so if you give allow an operation on a higher level node, you cannot take it away on a lower level. For that reason, you'll need to detect the condition on a higher level in the JSON structure.

So the solution is to use a `.write` rule, higher in the JSON tree.

```
  "test_tree": {
    ".write": "newData.exists() && (newData.hasChild('optionalString') || !data.hasChild('optionalString'))",
    ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['requiredString'])",
    "requiredString": {
      ".validate": "newData.isString()"
    },
    "optionalString":{
      ".validate": "newData.isString() || !data.exists()"
    },
    "$other": {
      ".validate": false
    }
```

I've simplified your data structure a bit, to only include a single required and a single optional property.

Comment: So, this is closer, but unfortunately it doesn't quite work. I was excited when the two tests that had previously failed now passed, but now a different one fails. **It looks like the "optionalString" property is no longer optional.** If I make a write request to the `test_tree` parent with all required children and completely remove `optionalString`, I receive a permission denied error.

Comment: I just wrote `{ requiredString: '1'}` without problems, *after* I removed the `optionalString` property from the database.

Comment: So, it is only optional *if there is no data at that location*? That seems half-optional. If writing to `test_tree` only with `requiredString` fails, then I don't think is a solution.

Comment: thoughts? I didn't do the `@mention` so you may have not gotten notification... **EDIT:** Why does this keep removing my mention to Frank?

Comment: *You don't need to @mention the person who wrote the post (question or answer).* You can only validate the `newData` at a location, not just the data being applied in an update. So there is no difference between writing `{ requiredString: '1' }` and `{ requiredString: '`', optionalString: null }`. Both would result in optionalString being gone from `newData`. It would probably be easier to help you, if you describe your use case and give some code of what you're trying to do. Security rules don't live in isolation, there's always code and a real-world use-case. Knowing that prevents XY problem

Comment: I think the formatting in your previous comment got a little messed up, FYI. ("...between writing `{ requiredString: '1' }` and `{ requiredString: '`, optionalString: null }`. Both would result in optionalString being gone from `newData`...)

Comment: I started writing out my use case, which at the time seemed very clear, but as I started to really get into the details things got very murky. Your point is well taken... I'll update my answer to reflect some of my thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

**This is all described in EDIT 1 above.**

I've spent some time thinking about my question, and I think the requirement is a little bit of a misnomer. Basically, what I was asking for was that the data be optional *if and only if* it's not present in the Firebase database. If it *is present* in the Firebase, it essentially becomes required.

However, once I realized that was the true requirement, it made describing the use case easier. Hopefully, it'll be clear in a moment, but basically **the use case is protecting the developer that is interfacing with Firebase from themselves.**

Imagine there is a tree of several descriptors for an item, and the tree looks like the following:

```
items: {
  item_ID1: {
    name: "Item Name",
    descriptorA: "A descriptor",
    descriptorB: "Another descriptor"
  }
}
```

Basically, I was thinking that `descriptorA` and `descriptorB` would be optional, and the `name` would be required. In the event that `name` needed to be changed whereas `descriptorA` and `descriptorB` would remain the same, I wanted to protect the developer that is writing the interface to this data from being able to accidentally blast `descriptorA` and `descriptorB` by using a `.set({item_ID1: {name: "New Name"}})`.

I think this actually can be accomplished with the following rules:

```
"rules": {
  "items": {
    ".write": "
      auth !== null &&
      newData.exists()
    ",
    ".validate": "
      newData.hasChild('name') &&
      (
        !data.hasChild('descriptorA') || 
        (data.hasChild('descriptorA') && newData.hasChild('descriptorA'))
      ) &&
      (
        !data.hasChild('descriptorB') || 
        (data.hasChild('descriptorB') && newData.hasChild('descriptorB'))
      )
    ",
    "name": {
      ".validate": "newData.isString()"
    ",
    "descriptorA": {
      ".validate": "newData.isString()"
    ",
    "descriptorB": {
      ".validate": "newData.isString()"
    ",
    "$others": {
      ".validate": false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If a user only wants to change `name`, why would they write the entire items/ path instead of just writing directly to `name`? What is the real use case here? Why is there an optional field that's required in some cases? How do you differentiate from a dev accidentally deleting a "quasi-optional" field vs. purposefully deleting it? A real use case would go a long ways here. This feels very much like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378), or maybe just some sort of over complex reasoning.

Comment: Potentially some over-complex reasoning. The answer to "why would they" is because they **could**. A dev should use `.update()`, but it's possible that they use `.set()` incorrectly. Again, the use case was explained as protecting developer from themselves -- which may be contrived, I haven't really decided yet. You mentioned purposeful deletion -- this is an important thing to consider, but the above rules do ensure that those data points are not deleted if they are defined (which was the question).

Comment: So, some simple answers here are that you can make `descriptorB` require `descriptorA` with a simple `.validate: "newData.parent().child('destriptorA').exists()"`. You can verify that fields are not deleted with things at the parent level like:  `"!data.child('descriptorB').exists() || newData.child('descriptorB').exists()"`.  Most of this you have, but in a bit more complex manner.

Comment: I have another related question about validating sibling nodes from a child node, but I'll ask it in another SO post.